# Error saving app settings - "Error There was a pr0blem saving your changes. Please try again later."

Tags: facebook, settings

Since a few days ago, when trying to change different settings for 2 of my 10 apps, I received the error: "Error There was a problem saving your changes. Please try again later."

This happens when I change any option.

Has anyone else gotten this problem? I'm not sure what to do as it only happens with a couple of my apps.

I read that this is not a problem with my app but with Facebook, but how do I get it resolved then?

Comment: Report it as a [bug](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs), this is not the right place for your question.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?